# Set value of multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm currently adding fileID to idarray[] and then do a foreach. But in addition to fileID I also need serverID and id in the array and the foreach, how do I do this? So basically I need to find out how to add 2 more values to the array and then also use those extra values in the foreach.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM redundfiles WHERE removed=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $idarray[] = $row['fileID'];
}

foreach ($idarray as $value)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM redundfiles WHERE fileID=$value AND removed=0 AND serverID=$XXXserverIDhereXXX");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM redundfiles WHERE id='".$XXXidhereXXX."' ";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean something like `$idarray[] = array($row['fileID'], $row['serverID'],...);`?

Comment: Oh god. _Three_ nested queries? You need to have a look at [MySQL JOINs](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php). Also, if we stick with the code you have above, you'll need to use a `for()` loop not a `foreach()`.

Comment: @Felix How would that affect my foreach loop? Will it become $value[1] $value[2] etc. ? MYSQL Joins confuse me like crazy because my spatial aptitude is extremely bad.

Comment: Instead of messing with silly array question I am curious of your queries What you expect from this pair: SELECT * FROM redundfiles WHERE removed=1 and SELECT * FROM redundfiles WHERE removed=0 AND fileID=$fileid ? it makes no sense to me. Your second query would return no results. What is your algorithm? I am sure it can be donr with just one query, without loops, arrays and all that mess

Comment: Yes, `$value` will be an array (and arrays indexes start with `0`).

Comment: The query will not necessarily return no results. I'm assuming redundfiles contains multiple rows with the same fileID. For example, if there is one row with [fileID=1, removed=1, word="freckles"] and another row with [fileID=1, removed=0, word="aardvark"], then the first query will return with "fileID=1" from the first row. And the second query will return with "word='aardvark'" from the second row.

Comment: The database can hold a fileID with both removed=1 and removed=0 at the same time so why would it return no results? You were right though, the array wasn't needed at all, it was a silly way if tackling the problem and I am now using an alternative. But it's still a good question that applies to different situations I guess.

Comment: so, you want your files to be synchronized? it's one join query indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just store the whole row into an array?

```
$rowarray[] = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM redundfiles WHERE removed=1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $rowarray[] = $row;
}

foreach ($rowarray as $row)
{
    $fileid = $row['fileID'];
    $serverid = $row['serverID'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM redundfiles WHERE fileID=$fileid AND removed=0 AND serverID=$serverid");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM redundfiles WHERE id='".$XXXidhereXXX."' ";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

But really, your whole code piece here is a mess. You can accomplish this way more efficiently using [JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)s.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that was possible!

Comment: you forgot one important line